# Is it necessary to dispose resources in Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am new to eclipse development, and while learning SWT, I came to know that I need to dispose the `display` using below fragment:

```
while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
}
display.dispose ();
```

So it disposes all of the OS resources acquired by display. My question is should I do the same thing in Eclipse plugin? Consider we have a `createPartControl()` code like this:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
      //Other codes
      parent.dispose(); //Shoud I compulsory do this in eclipse plugin?
}
```

Or will eclipse take care of disposing resource automatically? My assumption is I should dispose manually. Can you kindly correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Cleaning up resources appropriately is just a best practice for Java and all languages.  Assuming that it will be done automatically for your is asking for trouble at best and sloppy at worst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent.dispose()` is wrong way of doing it. you are supposed to clean up resources that you created in your composite. Do not dispose parent as it was not created by your view/composite.

Listen for dispose Event on Widget and do necessary cleanup.  Suppose you have created resource like Colors, Fonts, Images..etc in your View and you dont want to re-use them, listen for dipose event on your composite and dipose them.

```
yourComposite.addListener(SWT.dispose, new Listener(){

    public void handleEvent(Event e){
            image.dispose(); 
            font.dipose();  
            color.dipose()

    }

});
```